# Need help in reading callgrind output

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have run callgrind with my application like this:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind MyApplication
```

and then call:

```
callgrind_annotate --auto=yes ./callgrind.out.2489
```

I see output like:

```
 768,097,560  PROGRAM TOTALS

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Ir  file:function
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18,624,794  /build/buildd/eglibc-2.11.1/elf/dl-lookup.c:do_lookup_x
[/lib/ld-2.11.1.so]
18,149,492  /src/js/src/jsgc.cpp:JS_CallTracer'2
[/src/firefox-debug-objdir/js/src/libmozjs.so]
16,328,897 /src/layout/style/nsCSSDataBlock.cpp:nsCSSExpandedDataBlock::DoAssertInitialState()
[/src/firefox-debug-objdir/toolkit/library/libxul.so]
13,376,634  /build/buildd/eglibc-2.11.1/nptl/pthread_getspecific.c:pthread_getspecific
[/lib/libpthread-2.11.1.so]
13,005,623  /build/buildd/eglibc-2.11.1/malloc/malloc.c:_int_malloc
[/lib/libc-2.11.1.so]
10,404,453  ???:0x0000000000009190 [/usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2800.0]
10,358,646  /src/xpcom/io/nsFastLoadFile.cpp:NS_AccumulateFastLoadChecksum(unsigned
int*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, int)
[/src/firefox-debug-objdir/toolkit/library/libxul.so]
 8,543,634  /src/js/src/jsscan.cpp:js_GetToken
[/src/firefox-debug-objdir/js/src/libmozjs.so]
 7,451,273  /src/xpcom/typelib/xpt/src/xpt_arena.c:XPT_ArenaMalloc
[/src/firefox-debug-objdir/toolkit/library/libxul.so]
 7,335,131  ???:g_type_check_instance_is_a [/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.2400.0]
```

I have a few questions:

1. What does the number on the right mean? Does it mean it spend accumulative that long in calling the function on the right? How can I tell how many times that function has been called and Does that include the time spend in calling the functions called by that function?
2. What does line with `???` mean? e.g. `???:0x0000000000009190 [/usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2800.0]`

Answer (score 8):

Use KCachegrind. Deciphering the text output is just meaningless.

Comment: If you are using mac:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473185/do-you-have-kcachegrind-like-profiling-tools-for-mac

Answer (score 7):

As Let_Me_Be already answered, KCachegrind is the preferred way to go. Also make sure the `dot` command is available on your system in order to generate graphs with it. There's also the `callgrind_annotate` tool, which can do some basic processing at the command-line level.

Regarding your second question, these are calls inside libraries without debugging information. Usually it's not that interesting, but if you really need that information, you should compile the library yourself with debugging symbols (*and* optimization flags, since you're profiling).

Comment: But the program I want to profile is a gtk application ,but KCachegrind is a KDE application. What can I do ?

Comment: You don't need KDE in order to run KCachegrind. Having kdelibs should be sufficient, and it may already be installed on your system.

Besides, KCachegrind is not for profiling KDE applications, it can read any callgrind output.