# Need kcachegrind like profiling tools for mac

Tags: macos, macports, profiling

Need suggestion on tools similar to kcachegrind wingrind valgrind for mac platform.

I don't think these work on mac, I already checked these.

Comment: I am trying to profile php/javascript code, so more interested in those profilers. Thanks anycase for your inputs.

Comment: I think most browsers ship with their own Javascript interpreters, but Safari uses JavascriptCore which is exposed throughout the OS and therefore the thing that almost certain runs scripted Javascript content in other places like Cheetah3D. If you enable the 'Develop' menu in the preferences then there's a javascript profiler in there.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426799/is-there-any-kcachegrind-alternative-for-mac-os-x-outta-there/15952369

Answer (score 151):

I ended up using qcachegrind on OSX. It can be installed via brew

```
brew install qcachegrind
```

or, to enable *graphviz* support:

```
brew install qcachegrind --with-graphviz
```

What's great about this program is that I successfully loaded a 6.1GB cachegrind file on my MacBook Pro! Pretty slick!

Comment: `brew update` before doing this prevents weird erros :)

Comment: `brew install graphviz` if you want some pretty call graphs.

Comment: I had to symlink dot to get callgraphs to work   sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/dot /usr/bin/dot

Comment: from this, https://blog.josephscott.org/2013/07/03/qcachegrind-kcachegrind-on-mac-os-x/ in comments, to get around system protection to use dot: 
from @Motrin: This does no longer work in OSX El Capitan due to System Integration Protection:
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/dot /usr/bin/dot

Workaround:
$ cd /Applications/qcachegrind.app/Contents/MacOS
$ mv qcachegrind qcachegrind.bin
$ echo ‘#!/bin/bash
export PATH=”$PATH:/usr/local/bin”
$(dirname $0)/qcachegrind.bin
exit 0’ > qcachegrind
$ chmod +x qcachegrind

Then start qcachegrind as usual.

Comment: Re above comment from @Avibodha, make sure you replace the curly quotes with normal ones, and add newlines inside the qcachegrind file.

Comment: The `--with-graphviz` arg would not work for me (even after `brew update` and `brew doctor`), but then doing `brew install qcachegrind` and `brew install graphviz` as separate commands worked.

Comment: The Homebrew formula for qcachegrind has a dependency on graphviz, so the following suffices to install this in 2022 

`brew install qcachegrind`

Answer (score 67):

Try the qcachegrind + Graphviz killer combo.

It installs quickly via brew, which is nice.

Check out [these](http://langui.sh/2011/06/16/how-to-install-qcachegrind-kcachegrind-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard/) instructions, basically install it via:

```
brew install qcachegrind
```

which will download other dependencies such as `qt`and `graphviz`.

Comment: There is now a 'brew install qcachegrind' where the formula is based on that blog. Although it (atm) does not install the /Applications/QCachegrind.app, just a qcachegrind binary.

Comment: Another useful post: http://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au/2014/03/profiling-php-on-osx-with-xdebug-kcachegrind/

Answer (score 23):

You can install KCacheGrind using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

There are also some alternatives like:

- [WebGrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind)
- [qcachegrind](https://gist.github.com/justfalter/1029580) (`brew install qcachegrind`)
- [XHProf: A Hierarchical Profiler for PHP](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) (`pecl install xhprof`)
- [MCG](http://mcg-app.com/) premium app can analyse your application profile data natively on your Mac (released to the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mcg/id799178412?ls=1&mt=12) at $27)
- [Profiling Viewer](http://profilingviewer.com/), available on App Store at $25

  Older: [MacCallGrind](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33552/maccallgrind) (semi-commercial alternative, free version which is limited to 3MB grind files)

  [image: Screenshots of MCG app - xdebug - analyse your application profile]

  <sup>Image: [Homepage of MCG](http://mcg-app.com/)</sup>

See also: [Is there any KCacheGrind alternative for Mac Os X outta there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426799/is-there-any-kcachegrind-alternative-for-mac-os-x-outta-there/15952369#15952369)

Comment: for those who use phpStorm: it has a good built-in XDebug profile viewer (better experience than qcachegrind)

Answer (score 16):

Both valgrind and kcachegrind are available for Mac OS X.

You can install them using [MacPorts](http://macports.org):

```
sudo port install valgrind kcachegrind
```

Comment: i tried installing macports and did sudo port install valgrind kcachegrind, This was the error for both apps ------------------- Warning: No index(es) found! Have you synced your source indexes?
Error: Port kcachegrind not found---------------- any clue whats going on

Comment: The kcachegrind port was formally abandoned 2 years ago :( https://trac.macports.org/log/trunk/dports/devel/kcachegrind/Portfile

Comment: @Potatoswatter There are many ports in MacPorts that do not have a specific maintainer. This does imply that the port cannot be installed anymore.

Comment: @Raim It does imply that the port now installs software 2 years out of date.

Answer (score 8):

[Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind) runs in PHP and can read the cachegrind output of XDebug. It currently doesn't offer all the functionality of KCacheGrind, but it is super simple to install, and seems to have renewed activity.

Answer (score 7):

[MacCallGrind](http://www.maccallgrind.com/) is a semi-commercial alternative available for the Mac.  I've experimented with the free version which is limited to 3MB grind files.  It's roughly equivalent to [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) in terms of functionality.

Comment: Now purely commercial.

Answer (score 2):

Apple supply [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for monitoring runtime allocation of stuff and finding leaks, [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for explicit profiling and Guard Malloc (directly built into Xcode) for memory allocation debugging. These all come as part of the developer tools.

Comment: In recent OS X releases, Shark is now built into Instruments.

Answer (score 1):

valgrind is available for the mac. If you are building a cocoa app, you can use the tools that come with XCode such as leaks, they are very good.