# Is there any KCacheGrind alternative for macOS outta there?

Tags: php, macos, profiling, xdebug, kcachegrind

I'm looking for a KCacheGrind alternative, or at least a binary package for macOS?

I'd to use KCacheGrind with XDebug for PHP, but macOS is the right environnement here...

Thank you

Edit: I know I can use MacPort but I'm looking for an alternative of this painful installation.

Maybe something "in the mac way"

Comment: At least as of three years ago, kcachegrind was the only tool available for Macs.  I hope that has changed by now, for your sake.

Comment: I'm not a Mac expert, but you could use [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) if you can randomly interrupt php (like with Ctrl-C) and see what it's doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [do you have kcachegrind like profiling tools for mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473185/do-you-have-kcachegrind-like-profiling-tools-for-mac)

Answer (score 24):

You can install KCacheGrind using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/):

```
sudo port install valgrind kcachegrind4
```

There are also some alternatives like:

- [WebGrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind)
- [qcachegrind](https://gist.github.com/justfalter/1029580) (`brew install qcachegrind`); See: [installation steps on OS X](https://langui.sh/2011/06/16/how-to-install-qcachegrind-kcachegrind-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard/).
- [XHProf: A Hierarchical Profiler for PHP](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) (`pecl install xhprof`)
- [MCG](http://mcg-app.com/) premium app can analyse your application profile data natively on your Mac (released to the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mcg/id799178412?ls=1&mt=12))

  Older: [MacCallGrind](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33552/maccallgrind) (semi-commercial alternative, free version which is limited to 3MB grind files)

  [image: Screenshots of MCG app - xdebug - analyse your application profile]

  <sup>Image: [Homepage of MCG](http://mcg-app.com/)</sup>

See also: [do you have kcachegrind like profiling tools for mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473185/do-you-have-kcachegrind-like-profiling-tools-for-mac)

Comment: At the time of writing "kcachegrind has been made obsolete by the port kcachegrind4" - install kcachegrind4 instead.

Comment: kcachegrind4 is not compatible with MacOS Mojave

Answer (score 10):

You might want to check out [WebGrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind)

> Webgrind is an Xdebug profiling web frontend in PHP5. It implements a subset of the features of kcachegrind and installs in seconds and works on all platforms.

Comment: This. Takes only a minute to install. If you run it on the same server where you have your xdebug, it will even find and pick up the .trace files from /tmp.

Answer (score 9):

Another premium alternative is [ProfilingViewer](http://profilingviewer.com/), available on the Mac App Store. Handles multiple types of costs. Can display the data as Treemap, Callgraph, Flamegraph, Heatmap, can hide system functions and has a source file viewer annotated with the costs. Can create PDF's. Fast and has a small memory footprint.

[image: Profiling Viewer, Callgraph with Heatmap]

[image: Profiling Viewer, Treemap with Heatmap]

[image: Profiling Viewer, Flamegraph with Heatmap]

Comment: try this link: https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/profiling-viewer/id1079647046?mt=12&app=apps

Answer (score 7):

qcachegrind is the qt based 'cousin' of kcachegrind. Works like a treat.

Answer (score 3):

MacCallGrind and WebGrind is the true best answers for MacOS.
I can't comment kenorb answer so I have to make new one.

MacCallGrind link to MacUpdate is wrong - their's price is much higher then from developers site (http://www.maccallgrind.com/).

I personally find MacCallGrind grinder feature very useful in combine with Transmit (http://panic.com/transmit/) feature - mount ssh/sftp as disk. It automatically opens every new cache grind file that appears at remote location.

Comment: MacCallGrind war rename to MCG

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mcg/id799178412?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

You can now install qcachegrind with macports as well:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install graphviz qcachegrind
```

The app should appear in the Macports folder of your Applications

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative for KCacheGrind is PhpStorm Xdebug analyzer, that integrated with your source code and is very easy to find slow modules in your Magento project

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, this is much more convenient since I already had PhpStorm set up with Xdebug. You just have to set `xdebug.mode = profile` in your php.ini. This guide helped me:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/profiling-with-xdebug.html#analyze-xdebug-profiling-data